# C# Factories Issues

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, factory

So I've been working through some issues, and I'm real close, but I'm running into a problem.

So here's how I call my factory:

```
ClassImporter classImporter = new ClassImporter(importOptions);
```

There are multiple types of `ClassImporter` objects, here's the base `ClassImporter` class with one of the types.

```
public class ClassImporter
    {
        public ImportOptions Options;
        public ClassImporter Importer;

        public ClassImporter()
        {

        }

        public ClassImporter(ImportOptions options)
        {
            this.Options = options;
            this.Importer = ClassImporterFactory.GetImporter(options);
        }

        public virtual List<Class> Import()
        {
            return Importer.Import();
        }
    }

public class ExcelImporter : ClassImporter, IClassImporter
    {
        public ExcelImporter() : base()
        {

        }

        public override List<Class> Import()
        {
            if (base.Options.FileLocation == string.Empty)
            {
                throw new BlankFilenameException("A blank Excel file location was supplied.");
            }
            return new List<Class>();
        }
    }
```

And here's that `Factory` class you see in there:

```
public class ClassImporterFactory
    {
        public static ClassImporter GetImporter(ImportOptions options)
        {
            switch (options.FileType)
            {
                case FileType.CSV:
                    return new CSVImporter(options);
                case FileType.Excel:
                    return new ExcelImporter();
                case FileType.MySQL:
                    return new MySQLImporter(options);
                case FileType.Oracle:
                    return new OracleImporter(options);
                case FileType.ScreenScraper:
                    return new ScreenScraperImporter(options);
                case FileType.SQL:
                    return new SQLImporter(options);
                case FileType.XML:
                    return new XMLImporter(options);
                case FileType.NotSet:
                default:
                    throw new BlankImportTypeException("Import type was not specified in the Import Options.");

            }
        }
    }
```

Now I'm trying to `Assert` on that `Exception` you see in the `ExcelImporter` class, with this line:

```
classImporter.Import();
```

My test is attributed to have an `ExpectedException`, but it looks like when I debug through it, that the Importer hosted on the `ClassImporter` class is basically looking at it's own options instead of the base options of the main class that created it, and then therefore doesn't see the options passed in, just a null copy of them.

How can I redo this?

EDIT: Full Test:

```
[TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(BlankFilenameException), "A blank Excel file location was supplied.")]
        public void LoadExcelFile_EmptyName_ReturnsBlankFilenameException()
        {
            ImportOptions importOptions = new ImportOptions(FileType.Excel, string.Empty);
            ClassImporter classImporter = new ClassImporter(importOptions);

            classImporter.Import();
        }
```

Comment: I dont understand what you're saying the problem is; maybe you can post the test code?

Comment: IMO you want to ask the factory object ClassImporterFactory to create instances ClassImporter for you and to not allow ClassImporters to be created directly especially with the options thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExcelImporter's the only one of your classes that you're using the default constructor for. So it never sets the Options field. The parameterless base constructor doesn't set it either.
So, basically, you make a ClassImporter instance with the right options, and set its Importer property to a new ExcelImporter instance with no options.

You can fix this in a few ways, but the easiest way is to make ExcelImporter work the same as your other subclasses and have a constructor that takes ImportOptions. Then call that constructor from GetImporter. Don't chain them though - that'll loop forever.

Really, I don't understand why ExcelImporter's a derived class of ClassImporter. It doesn't use any of ClassImporter's functionality, and you're setting yourself up for an infinite loop with constructors. Just give it the options when you make the instance.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a `NullReferenceException`, aren't you?

When you do this:

```
public ExcelImporter() : base() {}
```

you aren't passing any `ImportOptions` to the base class.  So it can never be set, so at the line where you check the options, `base.Options` will always be null.

(But this design looks like it should pretty much loop forever when you create a `ClassImporter`, so I am unclear on what you're trying to accomplish)